# Render problem with lighting

Tags: lighting

it's my first time using Blender, and I'm having an issue. The red-highlighted light streak in the picture doesn't appear and disappears during rendering. Is there any way to make the rendered file look like it does in the preview? The light spot is projecting the image at the same time, but I really want to keep the light flare that appeared. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello maybe check in your Outliner if the object is enabled for render?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)